# iOS Auto Layout UIView Drawing cycle

Tags: ios, iphone

In one of the WWDC videos, Apple said that the layout is done from top down, ie from superview to subview (after constraints are calculated from bottom up). Display is also done from top down.

My questions are:
1. At what point in the viewcontroller is a view's frame (origin and size) determined? I tried to log the size of a view (defined using auto layout), but it was always 0 0  0 0, which is odd, because the view is already generated in the simulator;

For an autoresized view, when is view.frame available?

2. Same question, except this time it is UIImageView.frame. I tried to log to console,  even though the size is fit into the constraints, the logged UIImageView frame is 0 0 width_of_original_image height_of_original_image. But for other views like labels, the frame is printed correctly on the console.

It seems like that there is a mysterious auto layout engine that performs transform, and nobody knows what is going on inside the engine, but to check what is thrown onto the simulator display to figure out how the view was rendered by this engine???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not mysterious. It's quite simple! Think of constraints as instructions written down on pieces of paper - the views. Every once in a while, it's layout time! The runtime collects the pieces of paper from the views in order and obeys them - and so you end up with laid out frames.

So if you check sizes of things *before* layout time, you get the wrong answer because it hasn't happened yet.

And when *is* layout time? It's whenever the runtime sends views `layoutSubviews` - in fact, the runtime obeys constraints and performs layout *during* `layoutSubviews`. And your view controller can hear about this before or after, with `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

I think the part that confuses beginners the most is what happens when a view controller comes into existence. `viewDidLoad` means it *has* a view, but that is all; neither the view nor its subviews are in the interface yet, so obviously there can be no layout. Considerably *later*, we get `viewWillAppear:`, the view goes into the interface, and *now* we get layout. So if you check sizes in, say, `viewDidAppear:`, they will be right.

Comment: And see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_order_of_layout_events and http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_lifetime_events

Comment: Are these the same:    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
  relatedBy:0
  toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
  multiplier:1 constant:self.otherView.center.x]] vs.                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:self
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             multiplier:1.0
                             constant:0.0]];